# Unable to load jupyter notebook in VS code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I want to load a jupyter notebook in vs code. I have created a virtual env.
When I tried installing the ipykernel and import pandas library. I got this error:

> The kernel failed to start as 'ASTText' could not be imported from  'Python\Python38\site-packages\asttokens_*init*_.py''.

When I was working on a different project which was located in a different location, I did not receive any such error. Jupyter notebook worked fine.
Now i dont know why I am getting this error.

Comment: Have you activated the virtual environment and selected the kernel?